# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

i have a website with the following error in Codeigniter:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 166

This is the line.....

```
    $_classes[$class] = instantiate_class(new $name());
    return $_classes[$class];
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: `new $name()` needs to be assigned to variable in order to pass by ref.  `$obj = new $name(); $_classes[$class] = instantiate_class($obj);`

Comment: This is related to the php version you're using. You might need to extend the core to fix that.